# ASP.Net Link Button not working in Firefox (Version 8)

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have developed an ASP.NET application to use in Facebook. It has a simple link button which is used to work as expected in older versions of Firefox.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnLogOut" runat="server">Disconnect</asp:LinkButton>

 Protected Sub lbtnLogOut_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbtnLogOut.Click       
    Response.Redirect(Request.ApplicationPath & "/login.aspx")
  End Sub
```

After upgrading Firefox to 8, I noticed Link Button is not working i.e the button is not causing Post Back. When I view the source code, the Javascript code for Link Button to cause Post Back is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theForm.submit();
}
}
//]]>
</script>
```

I used Firebug to debug the above code but _doPostBack function is not firing when I clicked on Link Button. It is working in all other browsers (IE 9, Google Chrome, Safari) though.

Note: I am using this ASP.Net web application as App inside Facebook. Facebook basically displays this website inside it using iFrame.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55360/dopostback-is-not-working-in-firefox), but it does not provide any solution to me.
Wondering the issue is caused by Facebook iFrame or Firefox? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're assigning an event handler to the LinkButton.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" />
```

The JavaScript you posted is the `__doPostBack` function, which is not exclusive to the LinkButton. You are correct in the sense that LinkButtons use `__doPostBack` to trigger postbacks, but the function won't be called unless you assign an event handler to the LinkButton.

For debugging purposes, I would also set `CausesValidation` to false, just to make sure that validation doesn't interfere with the click event.

Comment: Try to explicitly declare the event handler in markup. For debugging purposes, I would also set `CausesValidation` to false. Validation might be the culprit too.

Comment: Handles lbtnLogOut.Click - Doesn't it automatically take care of OnClick property of the Link Button? The HTML rendered code for Link Button will be <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('lbtnLogOut','')" class="HLinkButton" id="lbtnLogOut">Disconnect</a>. So, clicking on the anchor link calls __doPostBack function which in turn does theForm.Submit()

Comment: OK..here is the thing. Magically it is working since this afternoon. My assumption is that since my application is a Facebook application (displayed in a iFrame inside Facebook website) Facebook API was conflicting/causing some problem with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code in your .master file or other appriopiate file just before the end `</body>` tag:

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   <!--
   function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
   var theform;
   if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
   theform = document.aspnetForm;
   }
   else {
   theform = document.forms["aspnetForm"];
   }
   theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
   theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
   theform.submit();
   }
   // -->
  </script>
```

Replace 'aspnetForm' with your own.